# Oracle SQL procedure to check input length

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I am trying to check the input length, to see if it's less than 7.  It should show an error message, but the code below doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prc_staffContact(IN_staffID IN CHAR, IN_staffContact IN VARCHAR) IS

    v_staffName VARCHAR(50);
    v_staffID CHAR(6);
    v_staffContact VARCHAR(11);


BEGIN

    SELECT s.staffName, s.staffID, s.staffContact
    INTO v_staffName, v_staffID, v_staffContact
    FROM staff s
    WHERE staffID = IN_staffID;

    IF (LENGTH(IN_staffContact) < 7 )
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error. Contact number at least 7 digits.');
    ELSE    
        UPDATE staff
        SET staffContact = IN_staffContact
        WHERE staffID = IN_staffID;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=============================================================================');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The contact number of [ ' ||v_staffName || ' ] has been updated successfully.');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('New contact number: [ ' ||v_staffContact || ' ].');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=============================================================================');

    END IF;

END;
/
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  Is the code not behaving like you expect?  If so, what behavior are you seeing?  What behavior do you expect?  What inputs are you passing the the procedure?

Comment: the procedure can create successfully, i update the contact number it shows [PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.] but doesn't checking even my input is less than 7 characters. and the data doesn't update also.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that I understand.  You say that you "update the contact number" which I assume means that you run the procedure and the procedure runs the UPDATE statement.  But then you say that "the data doesn't update also" which seems to imply the opposite.  You're claiming that the procedure isn't checking whether you input is less than 7 characters but you don't provide any evidence of that-- what are your inputs to the procedure?

Comment: after i run the procedure, then i type in exec prc_staffContact('100001', '0000');

Comment: We're getting closer but I'm still confused.  You run the procedure then you type in the second call to the procedure?  So there are two calls?  What is the first set of parameters?  What, exactly, do you expect to happen when you make the first call?  What, exactly, do you expect to happen when you make the second call?  What actually happens in both cases?  You say that you aren't getting compilation errors.  Are you getting runtime errors?  Are you seeing a behavior other than the one you expect?

Comment: the code i show in above i save it under procedure1.sql and i start it in sql plus. that is my 1st call. after that i call the exec prc_staffContact('100001', '0000'); isnt it should be perform the checking about the length of the contact number?

Comment: hmmm, it does perform checking but it just doesn't show the error message actually.. LOL so any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said something that appears to be contradictory:

> it shows [PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.] but doesn't checking even my input is less than 7 characters. and the data doesn't update also.

You described that you're doing as:

> i save it under procedure1.sql and i start it in sql plus. that is my 1st call. after that i call the exec prc_staffContact('100001', '0000')

Together those suggest that when you say the data isn't updated, what you really mean is you don't get the contact number/new contact number message from the `else` branch, and I think you're assuming that means the update doesn't happen either, so it didn't execute either branch. But you must have gone into either the `if` or the `else`, by definition.

So if you didn't get either message, then you haven't done:

```
set serveroutput on
```

in SQL*Plus before calling `exec`. [That setting is off by default](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2699298), unless you have it turned on in your `login.sql` or `glogin.sql`, so you have to turn it on explicitly if you want to see `dbms_output` messages.

---

In this case, for the validation, (a) you probably want the `select` inside the elsef` too, partly because (b) if the passed values doesn't exist you'll get a no_data_found exception, and (c) you might want to consider throwing an exception if the length is less than 7 rather than (only) displaying a message. Someone else calling this might not have serverout on either, or might be using a different client that doesn't have that option.

You've also got `v_staffID` defined as `char(6)`. Apart from wondering why that isn't a `varchar2`, the length you've given it means that if `IN_staffID` *is* 7 chars or more, the `select into` will get a 'character string buffer too small' error. I'd declare that as:

```
v_staffID staff.staffID%TYPE;
```

... to avoid issues like that, and the same for the other fields that relate to table columns.

And your 'success' message is showing the old contact number, not the new one. Not sure you need `v_staffContact` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code carefully. May be your **variable types not compatible** or stored procedure parameters not compatible with other variables (or table columns, column's types). I tested your code in my database, all success. but may be error **not data found** in your **select statement**, or may be buffer too small error. Hope this help you. thanks